# Beginners question on panel data/random model and variables depending on change to previous year

Tags: r, panel-data, random-effects-model

This might be a silly question, but... 
I have panel data including time variant variables (funding, number of investors and postsperday) as well as time invariant variables (city) that looks like this:

```
id year funding city     #investors postsperday 
1  1    0       0        2          3
1  2    0       0        2          5
1  3    1       0        4          4
1  4    0       0        4          4
1  5    1       0        3          4
2  1    0       1        1          0.5
2  2    0       1        1          n/a
2  3    1       1        2          2 
2  4    0       1        2          3
2  5    0       1        2          2.5
```

I'm wondering, if the change in posting frequency has significant influence on the funding probability. The variable would look probably sth. like this "postperdaydelta":

```
id year funding city     #investors postsperday postperdaydelta
1  1    0       0        2          3           
1  2    0       0        2          5              2
1  3    1       0        4          4             -1
1  4    0       0        4          4              0
1  5    1       0        3          4              0
2  1    0       1        1          0.5           
2  2    0       1        1          n/a          
2  3    1       1        2          2            
2  4    0       1        2          3              1
2  5    0       1        2          2.5         -0.5
```

Is this correct? I'm using R so would the Regression look like this:

```
panelrandom <- plm(funding ~ city + investors + postsperdaydelta, data = paneldata, model="random")
```

Or am I on the wrong track and need lagged data? Thank you!